# Adding an index to an existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I add an index to an existing model using the rails command line?
Is there something like `rails generate migration Add_Indexname_to_Tablename field_name:uniq` ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you'll want to take a look at the rails naming convention (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). I'm not sure whether you can generate the code for a unique index using the command line interface. Its probably much easier just to do it like Todd pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not fully understand the question and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe you can generate the complete migration. You'll have to create the migration and do `add_index(<table_name>, <column_name>, :unique => true)`.

Refer to the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) for full details.

Comment: I do it this way too, this is probably the easiest approach. Not that it matters, but I think the OP was asking how to run the generator using the rails migration naming convention so that the migration is properly set up in one shot, without having to manually edit it.